# Hide database row from adapter

Tags: android, listview, android-sqlite

I have a database being populated from a web service call. I am wondering how do I hide one of the rows from just the ListView? I don't want to delete the record just hide it so it doesn't show that row in the ListView as I am using that row to populate another ListView above. Is there a way to hide my a specific value in a column like employeeNumber?

I'm populating the ListView with a cursor and hoping there is a way to hide just the 1 row as I do not want that to show up in my ListView.

```
public void displayBottomList() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHandler.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor mBottomListCursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM employees", null);


        ListView mBottomListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mDirectReportList);
        BottomListViewAdapter bottomAdapter = new BottomListViewAdapter(this, mBottomListCursor);
        mBottomListView.setAdapter(bottomAdapter);
    }
```

Not really sure how to just hide that one row within this method using the Employee_number column from my database.

```
public class BottomListViewAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
    int position;

    public BottomListViewAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        super(context, cursor, 0);
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.contact_cardview_layout, parent, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
        view.setTag(viewHolder);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, final Cursor cursor) {
        final int pos = cursor.getPosition();
        final ViewHolder viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();

        String mFirstName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("First_name"));
        String mLastName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Last_name"));
        String mTitle = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Payroll_title"));
        String mThumbnail = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("ThumbnailData"));

        viewHolder.tvFirstName.setText(mFirstName);
        viewHolder.tvLastName.setText(mLastName);
        viewHolder.tvTitle.setText(mTitle);

        if(mThumbnail != null) {
            byte[] imageAsBytes = Base64.decode(mThumbnail.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
            Bitmap parsedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageAsBytes, 0, imageAsBytes.length);
            viewHolder.mPeepPic.setImageBitmap(parsedImage);
        } else {
            viewHolder.mPeepPic.setImageResource(R.drawable.img_place_holder_adapter);
        }

        viewHolder.mDetailsButton.setTag(cursor.getPosition());
        viewHolder.mDetailsButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                view.getTag();
                String mEmployeeNumber = cursor.getString(1);
                String mEmail = cursor.getString(8);
                String mFirstName = cursor.getString(2);
                String mLastName = cursor.getString(3);
                String mPhoneMobile = cursor.getString(4);
                String mPhoneOffice = cursor.getString(5);
                String mCostCenter = cursor.getString(10);
                String mHasDirectReports = cursor.getString(7);
                String mTitle = cursor.getString(6);
                String mPic = cursor.getString(9);
                Intent mIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), EmployeeFullInfo.class);
                mIntent.putExtra("Employee_number", mEmployeeNumber);
                mIntent.putExtra("Email", mEmail);
                mIntent.putExtra("First_name", mFirstName);
                mIntent.putExtra("Last_name", mLastName);
                mIntent.putExtra("Phone_mobile", mPhoneMobile);
                mIntent.putExtra("Phone_office", mPhoneOffice);
                mIntent.putExtra("Cost_center_id", mCostCenter);
                mIntent.putExtra("Has_direct_reports", mHasDirectReports);
                mIntent.putExtra("Payroll_title", mTitle);
                mIntent.putExtra("ThumbnailData", mPic);
                mIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                view.getContext().startActivity(mIntent);
            }
        });
    }/*

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if(convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from()
        }
    }*/

    public static class ViewHolder {
        TextView tvFirstName;
        TextView tvLastName;
        TextView tvTitle;
        ImageView mPeepPic;
        ImageButton mDetailsButton;
        CardView mCardView;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            tvFirstName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.personFirstName);
            tvLastName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.personLastName);
            tvTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.personTitle);
            mPeepPic = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.person_photo);
            mDetailsButton = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.fullDetailButton);
        }
    }

    /*@NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, @NonNull final ViewGroup parent) {
        final Employee employee = getItem(position);
        final AppViewHolder holder;

        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.contact_cardview_layout, parent, false);
        holder = new AppViewHolder();

        holder.tvFirstName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.personFirstName);
        holder.tvLastName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.personLastName);
        holder.tvTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.personTitle);
        holder.mPeepPic = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.person_photo);
        holder.mDetailsButton = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.fullDetailButton);
        holder.mCardView = (CardView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.home_screen_cardView);

        if (employee != null) {
            holder.tvFirstName.setText(employee.getFirst_name());
            holder.tvLastName.setText(employee.getLast_name());
            holder.tvTitle.setText(employee.getPayroll_title());

            if (employee.getThumbnailData() != null) {
                String peepPicData = employee.getThumbnailData();
                byte[] imageAsBytes = Base64.decode(peepPicData.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
                Bitmap parsedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageAsBytes, 0, imageAsBytes.length);
                holder.mPeepPic.setImageBitmap(parsedImage);
            }

            holder.mDetailsButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    String mEmployeeNumber = employee.getEmployee_number();
                    String mEmail = employee.getEmail();
                    String mFirstName = employee.getFirst_name();
                    String mLastName = employee.getLast_name();
                    String mPhoneMobile = employee.getPhone_mobile();
                    String mPhoneOffice = employee.getPhone_office();
                    String mCostCenter = employee.getCost_center_id();
                    String mHasDirectReports = employee.getHas_direct_reports();
                    String mTitle = employee.getPayroll_title();
                    String mPic = employee.getThumbnailData();
                    Intent mIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), EmployeeFullInfo.class);
                    mIntent.putExtra("Employee_number", mEmployeeNumber);
                    mIntent.putExtra("Email", mEmail);
                    mIntent.putExtra("First_name", mFirstName);
                    mIntent.putExtra("Last_name", mLastName);
                    mIntent.putExtra("Phone_mobile", mPhoneMobile);
                    mIntent.putExtra("Phone_office", mPhoneOffice);
                    mIntent.putExtra("Cost_center_id", mCostCenter);
                    mIntent.putExtra("Has_direct_reports", mHasDirectReports);
                    mIntent.putExtra("Payroll_title", mTitle);
                    mIntent.putExtra("ThumbnailData", mPic);
                    mIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    view.getContext().startActivity(mIntent);
                }
            });

            holder.mCardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    String mEmployeeNumber = employee.getEmployee_number();
                    Intent mListBottomListIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), MainActivity.class);
                    mListBottomListIntent.putExtra("Employee_number", mEmployeeNumber);
                    mListBottomListIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    view.getContext().startActivity(mListBottomListIntent);

                }
            });

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        return convertView;
    }*/
}

public class CustomCursorWrapper extends CursorWrapper {

    private String mStartingEmployeeID = "3500075";
    private Employee employee;


    public CustomCursorWrapper(Cursor cursor) {
        super(cursor);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        //if you want to exclude just one row
        return super.getCount() - 1;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean moveToPosition(int position) {
        boolean b = super.moveToPosition(position);
        if(employee.getEmployee_number() != null && employee.getEmployee_number().contains(mStartingEmployeeID)) {
            //if this is the row you wanna skip
            return super.moveToPosition(position + 1);
        }

        return b;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this a known row ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally this is Tricky because your cursor will have that entry. It would be a bit easier if the entry is at a fixed position within your cursor and preferably either at the head or the tail of the cursor. Also a cursor adapter automatically rolls over to the next entry when it invokes 'bindView' and I will not suggest fiddling with the cursor directly.
In case if you still want to go that way, Please remember not only do you have you have to override `bindview` but also the `getCount` methods on the adapter.

Edit : Or if the item you want to hide can appear at a dynamic position within the Cursor, then use a Cursor wrapper. Basically a CursorWrapper wraps around a Cursor and delegates all method calls to the underlying cursor. But you are free to override certain methods and insert your business logic. Sample is  -

```
public class CustomCursorWrapper extends CursorWrapper {

    public CustomCursorWrapper(Cursor cursor) {
        super(cursor);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        //if you want to exclude just one row
        return super.getCount() - 1;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean moveToPosition(int position) {
        boolean b = super.moveToPosition(position);
        if(false /*check whatever you have to check*/) {
            //if this is the row you wanna skip
            return super.moveToPosition(position + 1);
        }

        return b;
    }
}
```

API doc - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/CursorWrapper.html

Please note the above sample is just to show the usage. You might end up overriding few more methods. Give it a try

Edit 2 -

```
Cursor mBottomListCursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM employees", null);
CursorWrapper myWrapper = new CursorWrapper(mBottomListCursor );

ListView mBottomListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mDirectReportList);
BottomListViewAdapter bottomAdapter = new BottomListViewAdapter(this, myWrapper );
mBottomListView.setAdapter(bottomAdapter);
```

Comment: I have the bindView in my adapter class but do not have getCount. Also I am not really sure what to do with either to make that 1 row hidden.

Comment: Does that row come at a fixed position within your cursor ? Can you post your adapter code ?

Comment: It does for now, if the web service adds more data it would add more people either before or after that 1 row.

Comment: Edited my answer with a suggested sample. This way you need not fiddle either with the adapter or the view.

Comment: and do I call this to the mBottomListCursor after the query?

Comment: So what you do is create a cursor wrapper using the original cursor you have. And then use the Cursor wrapper as an input to the adapter.

Comment: CustomCursorWrapper mBottomListCursor = (CustomCursorWrapper) db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM employees" + " WHERE " + table + " NOT IN "+ "Employee_number", null); LIke this then? Sorry very new to cursors and cursor wrappers

Comment: Thank you, so in the moveToPosition, that is where I want to do the check for the employeeNumber I do not want to show? I have tried if(employee.getEmployee_number() != null && employee.getEmployee_number().contains(mStartingEmployeeID)) { but I am getting null on the Employee.getEmployee_number even though I am calling the cursorWrapper after making the database.

Comment: Provide your code post the changes. With the 2 lines you pasted in the comment it is difficult to say what are you trying to do and why it is failing. Anyways in `moveToPosition` you should read the field from the cursor (like employee id) and compare with whatever you want to compare it with and if certain conditions are met, call `cursor.moveToPosition` again to skip the current row

Comment: I added the CursorWrapper class

Comment: I could not see where your employee variable is being assigned. your code ideally should have been something like this -                `@Override
    public boolean moveToPosition(int position) {
        boolean b = super.moveToPosition(position);
        if(mStartingEmployeeID.equals(getString(getColumnIndex("employee_id")))) { // assuming you have a employee id columns
            //if this is the row you wanna skip
            return super.moveToPosition(position + 1);
        }
 
        return b;
    }`

Comment: This has worked to remove that 1 row I did not want, but now it is making a duplicate of the row after the 1 I am skipping.

Comment: I think you got the idea how to do it. Please debug and remove programming errors. The problems now you are facing would need someone to run the code and debug which you can do too. Give it a try

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134537/discussion-between-dibzmania-and-adam-gardner).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `SELECT * FROM employees` do `SELECT <column1>,<column2>,<column3>,... FROM employees`, listing all columns except for the one you want to hide.

Unrelated: DB access shouldn't be happening in the same layer as View interaction.

Edit: Skipping a row with a specific employeeNumber could be `SELECT * FROM employees WHERE employeeNumber <> <number you're not looking for>`

Comment: He is trying to hide a row, not a column.

Comment: I have changed it to ("SELECT * FROM employees" + " WHERE " + KEY_ID <> <mEmployeeNumberToHide>, null) and I am gettign an error at the <> <mEmployeeNumberToHid> saying its expecting a ). Is <> reconized in SQL?

Comment: `<>` is recognized in SQL, I doublechecked for sqlite, and it seems to be supported there as well. Your syntax seems off though, try `"SELECT * FROM employees WHERE KEY_ID <> " + mEmployeeNumberToHide` Edit: Everything that comes from Java variables need to be outside the quotes and concatenated with `+`, but everything else doesn't. The main problem is the missing quotes around `<>` however.

Comment: I would use `Select * WHERE employeeNumber NOT IN (list of values)`

Comment: So do I need to get my database and place them into a list then run the query? I am using a cursor.

Comment: You will need to change the query in the line `Cursor mBottomListCursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM employees", null);`

Answer (score 0):

If you can always identify this row, just add a check to `bindView` in your `BottomListViewAdapter`. If this is built-in default adapter, just extend it and edit this one function, all you have to do is return for a row that contains data that you want to hide.

Comment: I can always identify this row as I want to always hide it from this ListView. How would I hide the whole row and not the whole adapter?

Comment: You dont have to hide the whole adapter, in your adapter's bindView method, for every item in your dataset, it creates a layout and passed it to List. In this method, you can, for every item in your dataset (for every row) check whatever you want, for example, if it does not contains your value you want to hide, if so, simply return and continue with next element (row)